# Function.prototype.call and Function.prototype.apply with only one argument

Tags: javascript

What does Function.prototype.call or Function.prototype.apply do with only one argument?

What is going on here?

```
Function.prototype.myBind = function (context) {
  var fun = this;
  return function(){
    return fun.call(context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun.call(context)
```

the function in `fun` will be called with a context* of `context` and with no arguments passed.

This is essentially equivalent to calling:

```
context.temp = fun;
context.temp();
```

of course with `call` no additional properties would be added.

Here's an example:

```js
var a = {foo: 'bar'},
    b = {foo: 'baz'};

function example() {
  console.log(this.foo);
}

console.log('example called on a');
example.call(a); //'bar'

console.log('example called on b');
example.call(b); //'baz'
```

<sub>* `this` inside the function</sub>

Answer (score 4):

It calls the function without passing any arguments.

Comment: How is it different from "context.fun()"?

Comment: @WylliamJudd: `context.fun` doesn't exist.  `fun` is a variable, not a property name.